# Can't validate a dropdown after using .append with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following form:

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Product</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select class='dropdown' style="width:50%" id="dropdown1" name="dropdown1" required="required">
                            <option></option>
                            <?php echo $q1; ?> 
                        </select>
                        <span class="help-block">This is a description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Issue</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select class='dropdown' style="width:50%" id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2" required="required">
                        </select>
                        <span class="help-block">This is a description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Issue</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select class='dropdown' style="width:50%" id="dropdown3" name="dropdown3" required="required">
                        </select>
                        <span class="help-block">This is a description</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
<script>
//Support
$(document).ready(function() {
    var obj = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $all; ?>');

    $("#add_ticket_form").validate({
        errorClass: "help-inline",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
        }
    });

    $("select").select2({

    });

    $("#dropdown1").change(function() {
        $('#dropdown2').find('option').remove().end();
        if (obj[$(this).val()] !== undefined)
        {
            $('#dropdown2').append(obj[$(this).val()]);
            $('#dropdown2').rules('add', 'required');

        }
        else
        {
            //$('#dropdown2').attr('disabled', true);
            //$('#dropdown2').attr('required', false);
        }

    });
    $("#dropdown2").change(function() {
        $('#dropdown3').find('option').remove().end();
        if (obj[$(this).val()] !== undefined)
        {
            $('#dropdown3').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#dropdown3').rules('add', 'required');
            $('#dropdown3').append(obj[$(this).val()]);

        }
        else
        {
            $('#dropdown3').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#dropdown3').attr('required', true);
        }

    });

});
```

When I try to validate my form, without touching the dropdowns, the validator highlights each of them saying that they are required. However when I touch the first dropdown and change its value and click the button it says that the first AND THE 2ND dropdowns are correct and only the 3rd is incorrect. It looks like the problem is caused by the .append function since when I comment it out it works like a charm.

Comment: read jQuery documentation first

Comment: I've read the documentation but I can't see anything. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like .append causes the first element on the list automatically selected what is not visible when jquery select2 is applied. Modyfing the function to add an empty element solves the problem:

```
 $('#dropdown2').append('<option></option>' + obj[$(this).val()]);
```